# How to switch from List of rules to Association?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, associations

Considering we have a list of rules:

```
In[11]:= lst = {a -> {1 -> {A1, A2, A3, A4}, b -> 2}, c -> {3 -> C3, 4 -> C4}}

Out[11]= {a -> {1 -> {A1, A2, A3, A4}, b -> 2}, c -> {3 -> C3, 4 -> C4}}
```

Trying to make this an association parses only the beginning and the end of the list of rule:

```
In[13]:= Association@lst

Out[13]= <|a -> {1 -> {A1, A2, A3, A4}, b -> 2}, c -> {3 -> C3, 4 -> C4}|>
```

The output I would like to have is:

```
<|a -> <|1 -> {A1, A2, A3, A4}, b -> 2|>, c -> <|3 -> C3, 4 -> C4|>|>
```

How can I parse this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not pretty but works:

```
lst //. x : {__Rule} :> Association[x]
```

Comment: Wondering, why do you use {__Rule} and not {_Rule} ?

Comment: @penguin77 `{_Rule}` stands for something like `{a->2}` while we need to match one or more rules: `{a->2, b->3...}`.

Answer (score 19):

The undocumented function `ToAssociations` in the `GeneralUtilities` package does this

```
In[3]:= Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

In[4]:= ToAssociations[lst]

(* Out[4]= <|a -> <|1 -> {A1, A2, A3, A4}, b -> 2|>, 
c -> <|3 -> C3, 4 -> C4|>|> *)
```

As with any undocumented function, use with caution, as contents tend to shift during flight.

Comment: This is now also available as `ResourceFunction["ToAssociations"]`.

Answer (score 6):

This works too and it's theoretically faster than `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`):

```
asc = Replace[list, r : {__Rule} :> Association[r], {0, Infinity}]
```

The key observation is that `Replace` starts with the innermost levels first and works its way outwards.  In contrast, `ReplaceAll` and `ReplaceRepeated` start with the outermost levels and work their way inwards.

Comment: It's interesting to me that the reverse does not work, i.e.: `Replace[list, r : <|___Rule|> :> List[r], {0, Infinity}]`

Comment: @geordie `Association` is atomic. Its innards cannot be matched directly. There are tools like `KeyValuePattern` to extract information during matching. But what you'd do here is something like `a_?AssociationQ :> Normal[a]`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm still wrapping my head around `Association` as a useful construct. Lists of rules seem elegant enough!

Comment: @geordie The main reason is performance. Associations will always be faster, often *much* faster, then lists of rules. There is also a clear and concise syntax for extracting data, which does not exist for rule lists.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with a couple of different level specifications in `Map`, but it seems once the outer `List` becomes an `Association`, the other levels of `Map` are not used. So, instead, we apply it twice:

```
Map[Association]@Association@lst
(* <|a -> <|1 -> {A1, A2, A3, A4}, b -> 2|>, c -> <|3 -> C3, 4 -> C4|>|> *)
```

Comment: Then you have to apply it so many times as deep target rules are: `{a -> {1 -> {A1, A2, A3, A4}, b -> {b1 -> 1, b2 -> 2}}, 
 c -> {3 -> C3, 4 -> C4}}`

Comment: @Kuba for the OPs exact input, this works. But, you are correct, it isn't very general.

Comment: This goes to any level `lst //. x : {__Rule} :> Inactive[Association] @@ x // Activate`

Comment: @DanielW that's pretty ugle. I like yours better.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to say this.

Comment: I agree, but some people may not want to use undocumented functions.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the levelspec of Map and apparently this combination works. I have no idea what magic makes this work, though:

```
Map[Association, lst, {-6, -3}]
```

Or the following (from @Kuba's simultaneous edit):

```
Map[Association, lst, {0, -3}]
```

Comment: I tried something similar but it won't work if `Values` are going to be non atomic: `{a -> {1 -> {A1, A2, A3, A4}, b -> {b1 -> 1, b2 -> f[s[g[h]]]}}, 
 c -> {3 -> C3, 4 -> C4}}`.