# What does __Rule do in Mathematica?

Tags: pattern-matching

What does __Rule do in mathematica? I understand the __ is used for any repeated expression, but why is the Rule appended at the end?

For example:
[Import nested JSON file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84421/29963)

Thanks!

Comment: `_` matches anything while `_f` matches only expressions with head `f`.  Take a look at the first few sections here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html