# Extracting the graph of Keys in nested Associations

Tags: graphs-and-networks, associations, map

Related to this q: [Extract all Values from nested Association](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86150/801)

How to extract the direct graph of all `Keys` in nested `Associations`?

Mapping Keys doesn't seem to get at the deeper branches:

```
as = <|"a" -> <|"c" -> <|"e" -> 2|>, "d" -> 4|>, <|"b" -> 5|>|>
```

Then

as // Map[Keys, #, Infinity] &  /* Quiet

```
<|"a" -> {"c", "d"}, "b" -> Keys[5]|>
```

To limit application of keys to only Associations, can define the handler:

> keys[as_Association] := Keys[as]; keys[expr_] := expr

But even so:

```
as // Map[keys, #, Infinity] &
```

> <|"a" -> {"c", "d"}, "b" -> 5|>

Why isn't "e" included?

While the `Replace` based answer in the Q linked above works for `Values`, it does not work for `Keys`:

```
as //. a_Association :> Keys[a] // Flatten
```

> {"a", "b"}

Answer (score 3):

`Association`s are very different from mere lists of rules. For instance, they are atomic, so `Replace` cannot dive into them.

The replacement

```
as //. a_Association :> Keys[a] // Flatten
```

with  *does* work because one uses `//.` (a.k.a. `ReplaceRepeated`): After the first replacement, the outer association was removed and so the next round of replacement can attack the next level. Try `ReplaceAll` instead and you will see that it stops after the first level:

```
as /. a_Association :> Keys[a]
```

The following however works:

```
ToGraph[a_Association] := Graph[Flatten[{
     Map[x \[Function] DirectedEdge["root", x], Keys[a]],
     toGraph[a]
     }],
   VertexLabels -> "Name",
   GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"];

toGraph[a_Association] := {
   MapThread[
    {key, value} \[Function] If[AssociationQ[value],
      {Map[x \[Function] DirectedEdge[key, x], Keys[value]], toGraph[value]},
      {DirectedEdge[key, value]}
      ],
    {Keys[a], Values[a]}
    ]
   };

as2 = <|"a" -> <|"c" -> <|"e" -> 2, "f" -> 3|>, "d" -> 4|>, <|"b" -> 5|>|>
ToGraph[as2]
```

[image]

This is a slightly modified version of the code.

```
SetAttributes[AssociationToGraph, HoldAll];
AssociationToGraph[a_] := Module[{toGraph, data},
   toGraph[b_] := {
     KeyValueMap[{key, value} \[Function] If[AssociationQ[value],
        {
         Map[x \[Function] DirectedEdge[key, x], Keys[value]],
         toGraph[value]},
        {}
        ],
      b]
     };
   data = Flatten[{Map[
    x \[Function] DirectedEdge[ToString[Unevaluated[a]], x], Keys[a]], 
    toGraph[a]
    }];
   Graph[data, VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"]
   ] /; AssociationQ[a]

as2 = <|"a" -> <|"c" -> <|"e" -> 2, "f" -> 3|>, "d" -> 4|>, <|"b" -> 5|>|>
AssociationToGraph[as2]
```

[image]

Comment: Henrik, I would have though that `Map`-ping `Keys` would behave the same as `Query` at various levels but it's not the case. -- Thanks for the answer. Can you keep the current version but add a modification with (1) only keys, no values; (2) the name of the association instead of generic 'root' ?