# What is a proper transaction from nested rules to nested associations?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

Considering a list of rules `{A -> {A1-> B}}` what will be the correct way to come to `<|A -> <|A1-> B|>|>`?

Comment: `RulesToAssociations[rules_] := Replace[rules, r : {__Rule} :> Association[r], {0, Infinity}]`?

Comment: Actually you [have already asked the very same question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79390/how-to-switch-from-list-of-rules-to-association?rq=1) and received several answers.  Is there any problem with the solutions suggested there?

Comment: The issue is that the new functionality of associations does support lst //. x : {__Rule} :> Association[x] only with maximum iteration specification and returns list of associations, instead of associations.